# how to make python ignore the -tt option

Tags: python

First of all, I want to apologize for even trying to do this. I know that it's not recommended in any way. However, external constraints leave me little other choice than to go this path.

I have a piece of python code that lies on a read-only filesystem. I cannot move it. I cannot modify it. It has an inconsistent use of tabs and spaces. And I need this code to be importable with the `-tt` option.

Is there any way to ignore the `-tt` option for a specific `import` statement, a specific code section, or a certain application altogether?

Comment: could you copy it elsewhere and modify this copy?

Comment: The file is part of a larger software release and is imported via a long chain. Hence, I would need to copy the entire release to a local space to make this work. Since the code should run on a batch system, this is not really an option, as this would mean copying several hundred megabytes of code for every time the code starts running on any batch node.

Comment: Ask the vendor to fix their software - I would NOT rely on python code that "has an inconsistent use of tabs and spaces.".

Comment: Done, but will take 4 weeks to become deployed, hence will delay further development in an unacceptable fashion.

Comment: Tried with 2.7.10 and 3.4.3 `-tt` only seems to apply for 3.4.3. 2.7.10 doesn't complain when you import a module that as inconsistent use of tabs and spaces, although it does complain if you try to run the module directly. So... could you use python 2? Horrible, I know.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I am using 2.7.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully admit that this is a horrible, horrible solution. I await the downvotes:

dodgymodule.py:

```
def somefunc():
        print("This is indented using 4 spaces")
        print("This is indented using a tab")
```

main python script, which uses autopep8 to fix the code and import the resulting string instead:

```
import autopep8
import imp

try:
    import dodgymodule
except TabError as e:
    with open(e.filename, 'r') as f:
        new_module_contents = autopep8.fix_code(f.read())
        dodgymodule = imp.new_module('dodgymodule')
        exec(new_module_contents, dodgymodule.__dict__)

dodgymodule.somefunc()
```

`python3 -tt script.py` prints out the lines, as hoped.